# How to call api again after clearing interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to create a stack area graph from the values I get from api's.
My first api gives me a range of dates. Eg: June 1 - June 7.
My second api gives me values need for the graph. The data looks like this

My idea is to call the api and push the count values to function every time to a function. But somehow I could not make that possible so I am calling api once for every 100 ms and grabbing all the data and triggering the graph. Now when I want to call the second api after one iteration is complete the call interrupts the graph. Please help me fix this.

```
 d3.json('/service/dates', function(error, dates) {
    var dran = dates;
    if (dates != null) {
      sDt = new Date(dates.st);
      eDt = new Date(dates.et);
      var i = 0;
      var start = function() {
        if (sDt > eDt) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          $('.wrapper').trigger('newPoint');
          return;
        }
        var sDate = sDt.toISOString();
        var eDate = new Date(sDt.setMinutes(sDt.getMinutes() + 30)).toISOString();

        //Calling the api for graph values
        d3.json("/service/dat?s=" + sDate + "&e=" + eDate, function(error, results) {
          if (results != null) {

            numbers = numbers.push(results.numbers);
            values = values.push(results.values);
          }
        });
        i++;
      }
      var interval = setInterval(start, 100);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: you're calling `setInterval`, you need to clear twice too.

Comment: I mean you're calling it two times, second call inside `func` is never cleared.

Comment: @Haravi Why did you edit out the code? It renders the question completely useless and leaves the accepted answer dangling without any meaning.

Comment: @altocumulus That happened accidentally when I was editing it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the entire API call inside a named function. Then call that from the `start()` function to restart everything.

```
function doAPILoop() {
  d3.json('/service/dates', function(error, dates) {
    var dran = dates;
    if (dates != null) {
      sDt = new Date(dates.st);
      eDt = new Date(dates.et);
      var i = 0;
      var start = function() {
        if (sDt > eDt) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          $('.wrapper').trigger('newPoint');
          doAPILoop();
          return;
        }
        var sDate = sDt.toISOString();
        var eDate = new Date(sDt.setMinutes(sDt.getMinutes() + 30)).toISOString();

        //Calling the api for graph values
        d3.json("/service/dat?s=" + sDate + "&e=" + eDate, function(error, results) {
          if (results != null) {

            numbers = numbers.concat(results.numbers);
            values[values.length] = results.values;
          }
        });
        i++;
      }
      var interval = setInterval(start, 10);
    }
  });
}

doAPILoop();
```

Comment: What graph are you talking about?

Comment: After you restart it, what happens to `num1` and `num2`? Because when it repeats in 30 minutes it will check them again, and if `num1 > num2` it will run the code that clears and restarts it, and doesn't go into the `//do something` code.

Comment: If `num1 <= num2` then it should execute the `// do something` code. I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: What normally updates those variables? Is that still happening?

Comment: I don't see how it can increment by 10 minutes when you do`setMInutes(getMinutes()+30)`.

Comment: I don't understand what you want it to do when it reaches the end time. If you don't want it to keep adding to the time, why do you need to restart the timer?

Comment: Why do you need to restart the interval when the flag is true? Nothing is stopping the interval when that happens.

Comment: Do you want to make the API call again? Put the entire thing inside a named function. When you reach the end, clear the interval, and then call the original function that performs the API call and starts the timer.

Comment: Yeah, I renamed the function while I was writing, and forgot to update that line.

Comment: Thanks Barmar! This worked to call the Api but having issues with the graph whenever a new API is called my graph hops suddenly. Its smooth flow is disturbed!

Comment: Maybe you should trigger `newPoint` every time you get a value, not just when you restart.

Comment: My actual idea is to have a call the api every 2.5 secs to get a new value. But for some reason if I am calling function start for 2.5secs my graph starts after 40 mins. Not sure why so I am calling it for 10ms and after all the calls are done my graph is starting in 5secs. This is annoying, there should be a better way to do it but I don't know how!

Comment: It doesn't trigger `newPoint` until it reaches the end time. Is that what updates the graph?

Comment: Yes, you are right ! Once it reaches end time my graph starts!

Comment: Then you need to do that more often, like every time you perform the `dat` API call, not just when you restart.

Comment: so you want me to trigger the newPoint before the doAPILoop() that we declared at end also ?

Comment: I think you should do it after `values[values.length] = results.values;`

Comment: BTW, that can be simplified to `values.push(results.values)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115542/discussion-between-haravi-and-barmar).